# State value holding array data from previous user when new user logs in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In my `fetchRequestByEmployee`, I'm trying to use an axios request to pull the requests by the `employeeId`. However, it's not recognizing the string interpolation. If I hardcode in the `employeeId` it works just fine and renders the page correctly, but when using the interpolation, it doesn't.

I have done a console log to make sure it is pulling in the id correctly from context.

I'm trying to render the page based on the token and the employeeId. The token and the user are set to null when a user logs out, but the app acts like it is circling back around to process the axios request a second time. If I refresh the page, it is fine, but I don't want to require the user to refresh each time they log in so they get the proper information.

Here is where the user information is pulled from app.js based on who is logged in.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchEmployeeInfo = async() => {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees/user/${user.id}/`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      });

      setEmployeeData(response.data);
      setEmployeeInfo(response.data);
      setEmployeeId(response.data.id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
  fetchEmployeeInfo();
}, [user, employee, token]);
```

This is the UseEffect from the homepage that gets the ptoRequest information based on the user.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPtoRequestByEmployee = async(employeeId) => { //add async before parenthensis ahead of the arrow function
    console.log(employeeId)
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pto_requests/employee/${employeeId}/`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      });
      console.log(employeeId)
      console.log(response.data)
      setPtoRequests(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  };
  fetchPtoRequestByEmployee();
}, [token, employeeId, ]);
```

This is the code to logout the user.

```js
const logoutUser = () => {
  if (user) {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    setUser(null);
    setToken(null);
    navigate("/");
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi! Your code formatting is very, very broken here and there's a LOT of code; often here in StackOverflow questions like this get a lot less attention. Try making a minimal, focused example of the issue showing the relevant code that's formatted well. Is the `div className = "column1" >` for example important for the question? Is `element = { < AdminPage employeeData = {` important for this issue? Also, these would be better as straightforward code blocks. Right now it's really hard for us to focus on the main point of your question. Maybe browse https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: Hi @JoelPeltonen, I have updated my question to make it a little more user friendly.

Comment: Hmmmmh. If empoyeeId is the same variable as `setEmployeeId(response.data.id);`  and that's the thing that is not being reset during logout, I think your logout needs to call `setEmployeeId(null);` as well, right? I might be misunderstanding it though.

Comment: Still no luck. I even tried another `axios` call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pto_requests/employee_number/3/` to call the requests by `employee_number` instead of `employeeId` and it's still returning the `pto_requests`

Comment: Is this open source by any chance? What a curious thing.

Comment: It is not. I'm running it locally.